# Alembic migration for GeoAlchemy2 raises NameError: name 'geoalchemy2' is not defined

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, alembic, geoalchemy2

I've decided to write a small webapp using Flask, postgresql and leaflet. I wanted to store coordinates (latitude and longitude) using [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) extender for postgresql. My flask application uses Flask-SQLAlchemy, blueprint and especially Flask-Migrate for the database migration process.

Here is an excerpt of my database model:

```
from . import db
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry


class Station(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stations'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    position = db.Column(Geometry('Point', srid=4326))
```

Here an excerpt of my app/**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_name=None, main=True):

if config_name is None:
    config_name = os.environ.get('FLASK_CONFIG', 'development')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

db.init_app(app)
migrate.init_app(app, db)

from .home import home as home_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)

from .admin import admin as admin_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')

return app
```

Before trying to use the specific extender, I didn't have any issue to adapt my model. Since then, the migration is doing alright but the upgrade doesn't work (python manage.py db upgrade).

Here the log I obtain from the webserver:

```
sa.Column('position', geoalchemy2.types.Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326), nullable=True),
`enter code here`NameError: name 'geoalchemy2' is not defined
```

I'm a bit lost and I didn't find much help on this specific subject. Any idea on what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alembic does not try to determine and render all imports for custom types in the migration scripts.  Edit the generated script to include `from geoalchemy2.types import Geometry` and change the column def to just use `Geometry`.

You should always review the auto-generated scripts before running them.  There's even comments in the script saying so.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this which doesn't require manually editing the revision is adding `import geoalchemy2` into `alembic/script.py.mako` and then alembic adds the module every time.

```
"""${message}
  
Revision ID: ${up_revision}
Revises: ${down_revision | comma,n}
Create Date: ${create_date}

"""
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import geoalchemy2 # <--- right here
${imports if imports else ""}

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = ${repr(up_revision)}
down_revision = ${repr(down_revision)}
branch_labels = ${repr(branch_labels)}
depends_on = ${repr(depends_on)}


def upgrade():
    ${upgrades if upgrades else "pass"}


def downgrade():
    ${downgrades if downgrades else "pass"}
```